# Jquery post method searching servlet in webcontent

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

i am trying to call servlet using jquery post but instead of calling the servlet it is searching for servlet in jsp part of webcontent.
i am posting the code below

```
function getPackageList() {
    alert("in package List");
    var Criteria = "get_package_list";
    var list;
    // $('#package_list').empty();
    $.post(
            '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PackageController',
            {
                criteria : Criteria
            },
            function(data) {
                alert("Success " + data);
                $(data).each(
                        function(index, element) {
                            list += "<li> <a href='#' id='" + element.Id
                                    + "' onClick='getSelectedPackage()'>"
                                    + element.PackageName + "</a></li>";
                        });
                $('#package_list').html(list);
            }, 'json').fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(error);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
}

@WebServlet("/PackageController")
public class PackageController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static PackageDao packageDao = new PackageDaoImpl();

    public PackageController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String criteria=request.getParameter("criteria");
        System.out.println("The criteria is "+criteria);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            String criteria=request.getParameter("criteria");
            System.out.println("The criteria is "+criteria);

            if(criteria.equalsIgnoreCase("get_package_list"))
            {
                List<Package> packageList = packageDao.getPackageList();
                Iterator <Package> itTemp = packageList.iterator();
                JSONObject json=null;
                JSONArray json_data_array= new JSONArray();
                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                System.out.println("The List Size is "+packageList.size());

                while(itTemp.hasNext())
                {
                    Package packageTemp = itTemp.next();
                    json = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        json.put("Id", packageTemp.getPackageId());
                        json.put("PackageName", packageTemp.getPackageName());
                        json_data_array.put(json);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("Id", "custom");
                json.put("PackageName", "Customise Package");
                json_data_array.put(json);

                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                out.print(json_data_array);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

the error i get in fire bug console is as
health/jsp/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/PackageController
404 not found

Answer (score 0):

Remove `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` from the ajax post.

```
  `$.post(
        'PackageController',
        {
       -------`
```

Hope this helps you.